# How to find the minimum value between three (for loop)?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I need to find the minimum of sonarRange[i], sonarRange2[i] and sonarRange3[i]. Each one of the three previous arrays is in an individual (for loop) as it showed the code

I used the If statement to calculate the minimum value. It works but I wrote much code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sonarSensor[i] = robot.getSonarReading(i);
        sonarRange[i] = sonarSensor[i]->getRange();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sonarSensor[i] = robot.getSonarReading(i);
        sonarRange2[i] = sonarSensor[i]->getRange();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sonarSensor[i] = robot.getSonarReading(i);
        sonarRange3[i] = sonarSensor[i]->getRange();

    }
```

Comment: your code is not calcualting any minimum... anyhow, I think you are looking for [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)

Comment: Put the 3 values into an array, then then use [`std::min_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) to find the minimum value in that array

Comment: do you want to find the minimum in each array or do you want to find the minimum among the three arrays for each index?

Comment: btw if your question is about code you better show the code, the part you posted is only remotely related to the question. See also: [mcve]

Comment: btw if you find yourself naming variables `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` it is likely that you rather want a `vector` called `foo`.

Comment: I want to find the minimum among the three arrays for each index

Comment: @Farhan I added an update to my answer since I started to suspect that you are using VS2015 and that it doesn't support the version of `std::min` I used in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [std::min_element ()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) to find the minimum element of each array an then use [std::min ()](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) to find the minimum of the three values.

Comment: question wasnt quite clear, but in comments it turned out that OP wants something else

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find the minimum among the three arrays for each index

As Remy Lebeau suggested, put them inside an array and use [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element):

```
for (size_t i=0;i < 8; ++i){
    std::array<int,3> x{ sonarRange[i], sonarRange2[i], sonarRange3[i] };
    int min = *std::min_element(x.begin(),x.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 plain arrays with 8 elements in each, this should be sufficient:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using range_type = double; // change to the type you are using

int main() {
    range_type sonarRange[8];
    range_type sonarRange2[8];
    range_type sonarRange3[8];

    // fill sonarRanges

    // find and store the minimum at each index
    range_type result[8];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        result[i] = std::min({sonarRange[i], sonarRange2[i], sonarRange3[i]});
    }
}
```

If your compiler does not accept that version of `std::min`, you can add it yourself:

```
<initializer_list>
template<class T>
T my_min(std::initializer_list<T> ilist)
{
    return *std::min_element(ilist.begin(), ilist.end());
}
```

And then use `my_min({sonarRange[i], sonarRange2[i], sonarRange3[i]})` instead of `std::min` above.